# How to make spring cloud contract tests on controller with secured methods with annotation @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-cloud-contract

I'm writing Spring Cloud Contract tests on MVC Controller whith has methods with annotation `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")`. What do I need to provide for passing the security of methods? 
I need to test security of controller. 
Oauth2 security using in project.
I'm junior dev (many things I dont know yet) and it would be greate if you provide me extended answers. 
Thanks.

I've created base test class where provided mockMvc in setup() method with annotation @Before.

Base test class has the looking form:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = AdminController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AdminControllerTestConfig.class, TestConfig.class, AdminControllerTestProperty.class})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = AdminController.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "/AdminControllerTest.properties")
@AutoConfigureStubRunner(workOffline = true)
public class AdminControllerContractBaseTest {
    //code
}
```

setup method for autogenerated contract tests

```
@Before
    public void setup() {
        Admin admin = createAdminUser();
        when(adminRepository.findOneByCredentialsId(id)).thenReturn(admin);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new AdminController(adminService, credentialsService));
        MockMvc mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }
```

tests methods for autogenerated test classes

```
    @Test
    public void shouldFindAdminUserById() {
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldNotFindAdminUserById() {
    }

    @Test
    public void userDoesNotLoggedIn() {
    }
```

I know that I'm not providing any deteils about login user for security but I didn't find info about how to do it in my situation with contract tests.

I've tried to set annotation `@WithMockUser(roles = "ADMIN")` on test methods but it doesn't works.

Maybe I didn't configure enough for passing tests?
By the way I have email and password of user who has access to this API.

In autogenerated tests on method below which according to contract

```
ResponseOptions response = given().spec(request)                     
    .get("/api/admin/a")
```

I expected response code `200` after passing tests but actual code is `401`

Comment: How did you  write your test cases then ? 
I need to do something similar.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to write an integration test with `@SpringBootTest` instead of using Spring Cloud Contract to test your security.
Spring Cloud Contract has been created to verify the in- and output of your communication layer and to let you (the producer) know if you're going to break your API so others (the consumers) have a problem using your exposed API.

Please take a look at this [sample](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer/) on how you can setup your Spring Cloud Contract tests without starting the whole application context.

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: you are right, but there are problems with setup of application that uses spring security: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: springSecurityFilterChain cannot be null. Ensure a Bean with the name springSecurityFilterChain implementing Filter is present or inject the Filter to be used.`